# Cauchy-Hadamard with Triple Powers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to determine the convergence radius of this series:
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{3n}}{3n\sqrt{n}\cdot8^n}}
$$
I defined
$$
a_n=
\begin{cases}
    \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3n\sqrt{n}\cdot8^n} & \text{if } n = 0 \bmod{3}\\
    0              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
And hence $(\ast)$
$$
f(x) = \sum{a_nx^n}
$$

So, we can use Cauchy-Hadamard to determine the radius:
$$
\frac{1}{R}=\lim_{n \to \infty}{\sup \sqrt[n]{\left| \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3n\sqrt{n}\cdot8^n}\right|}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3n]{3\cdot3n\sqrt{3n}\cdot8^{3n}}}}=\frac{1}{8}
$$

Therefore $R = 8$. However, the official answers (and my computer) say that $R=2$, although my limit calculation seems to be correct.

Since we're dealing with $3n$ powers, and $2^3 =8$, I presume I missed something when transitioning to the "cannonical" form of the series at $(\ast)$.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You went wrong in two places

(1) you redefined $f$, in fact your $a_n$ should have been
$$
a_n=\begin{cases}
\frac{(-1)^{n/3+1}}{n\sqrt{n/3}2^n} & n\equiv 0\pmod{3}\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
to recover $f(x)=\sum a_nx^n$.

(2) $\frac{\pm1}{3n\sqrt{n}8^n}$ is the coefficient $x^{3n}$, not $x^n$.  So you should take its $3n$-th root instead:
$$
\frac1R=\limsup\left\lvert\frac{\pm1}{3n\sqrt{n}8^n}\right\rvert^{1/(3n)}=\frac12.
$$

Comment: Ahh, I get it. Thanks. Will mark as the anwswer ASAP.